# How do I make a 16-digit query containing both numbers and characters?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).on('input','#coupon_code',function(e){
        var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})/);
        e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '') + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="coupon_code" />
```

The code above provides only the numerical one. How can I do this both as numbers and characters?

for example: **KFOW-24QF-RWW1-EEW1**

I want to use as in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\D` and `\d` with `[^a-z0-9]` and `[a-z0-9]`. `\d` is for digits only. `\w` is for words, but it allows e.g. underscore too, so does not fit here:

```js
$(document).on('input','#coupon_code',function(e){
        var x = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '').match(/([a-z0-9]{0,4})([a-z0-9]{0,4})([a-z0-9]{0,4})([a-z0-9]{0,4})/i);
        e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '') + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');
        e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="coupon_code" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to enlarge the entered value. How do I make it?

Comment: @ops Enlarge? Do you mean to make it uppercase? Possible, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the unwanted characters and replace four characters with and additional dash.

```js
$(document).on('input','#coupon_code',function(e){
        e.target.value = e.target.value
            .replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '')
            .replace(/....(?=.)/g, '$&-')
            .toUpperCase();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="coupon_code" />
```